# How to update MySQL table with some math?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm writing a php script which will update my sql `filed` with some math.
Should I make a query to get the filed value first then update the filed or there is something to update the filed with in the query it self
here is the math

```
$sum = 5 ;
$filed = $filed +(($filed * 100) / $sum) ;
```

This how the math goes with in the PHP.
Is there any way to get this math done by the query it self ?

Comment: Are `$sum` and `$filed` somewhere in the DB?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Assuming `filed` is the name of a column in your table, you can do the math right inside the MySQL query, without involving PHP:

```
UPDATE table SET filed = (filed + ((filed * 100) / 5) WHERE some_condition;
```

Just be sure to set the appropriate conditions in your `WHERE` clause so you don't update rows you don't intend to update.

Comment: thank you so much its going to update all the table values so no need to use a condition